# C and enumerations

Tags: c, enumeration

What's the advantage of creating a variable of `enum` type? I know how to define an enum type, and a variable - however, I don't quite see the advantage?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    enum colour{
        white,
        red=2,
        green,
        blue,
        yellow,
        black
    } jacket;

    jacket=50;
    int shirt=yellow;
    printf("%d\n",jacket);
    printf("%d",shirt);

   return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `jacket` is defined as `enum` but `shirt` is defined as an integer. The `enum` type doesn't prevent me from using a value that isn't specified as an element. Nor does the `integer` type prevent me from assigning it to a value from the `enum` type.

The above code gives the following output:

```
50
5
```

What's the functionaly difference, if any, between these variables?

Comment: Just for the record, Java, C++, and C# all have more advanced uses of enum, where the advantages are even more clearly delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `enum` is just a way of giving constants symbolic values; the constants are just integers' There are a couple of advantages to this, compared to defines: The values, if consecutive, are automatically created, and an `enum` obeys block scope. It also tells other programmers that you except the variable to only take on those values. A debugger can show the symbolic names, which can be helpful instead of just showing the raw values.

Comment: Add to that the fact that it makes code maintainability much easier.  Let's say that "jacket" should be changed to be represented by 51, instead of 50.  This will have to be changed in all places in code that need to compare against jacket.  On the other hand, if you were to add a value to your enum above "yellow", it will change the __value__ of yellow, but your __usage__ will not need to change at all

Answer (score 3):

> What's the functionaly difference, if any, between these variables?

`shirt` and `jacket` are both of integer types but `shirt` is `int` and is `enum colour`. The latter is an implementation defined integer type and can be `unsigned int` for example.

In `gcc` for example, by default `enum colour` is `unsigned int`.

Now using variable of `enum` type has some advantage. For example, some compilers are able to detect and warn the mix-up of different `enum` types. Also if you use an object of an `enum` type as the controlling expression of a `switch` statement, some compilers (e.g., `gcc` with `-Wswitch`) are able to warn if you don't list all `enum` constant cases. Also debuggers are usually able to display some nice symbols for `enum` objects values.

Answer (score 1):

Which code is more easily understandable?

```
Tshirt tee = new Tshirt();

tee.setColor(4);
```

or

```
enum color { red, green, blue, black, pink, grey, brown };
Tshirt *tee = new Tshirt();

tee.setColor( pink );
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages is, it increases program readability.

For example:

```
enum colour{white, red=2, green, blue, yellow, black} jacket;

int shirt_price[10];

shirt_price[red] = 50;
shirt_price[green] = 100;
shirt_price[black] = 500;
```

Now you don't need to remember the indexes here just use enum variable.